# Clear the previous data and refresh output in `global()` or `locals()`

Tags: python

Accumulated over hours, there's a mountain of date when use `globals()` or `locals()` in interactive console.

How to clear the previous data ?

Comment: ... close the console window and open a new one?

Comment: so, there is no alternative.

Comment: `globals()` and `locals()` return dictionaries, and these can be be modified in the usual way, including using the `clear()` method. But there are certain entries in `globals()` (notably `__builtins__`) that are required by Python, so you have to be careful not to wipe those out. So, the easiest way is to start a new interpreter.